# wordpress post images in accordion not showing up in some of the pc

Tags: posts

i am having an issue image loading...
For some certain times, the images i added into the accordion content wasn't able to load properly....
It happens in certain PC but it perfectly well in some PC...
Somehow the image shows after refresh on the same page itself..
i wondering how to solve this issue.

here's the site for references
http://alphafertilitycentre.com/treatment/

thanks
Shiyi

Answer (score 1):

I think that the images are not showing correctly because you have javascript errors on the page, you should first solve
[image: Error javascript theme]